# Waiting async in Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

I am trying to write a Matrix server client application with Flutter.

I request groups from the server that the user is a member of.

```dart
Future<List> joinedRooms(String accessToken) async {
  String url = server + "/_matrix/client/r0/joined_rooms";
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken"};
  Response response = await get(url, headers: headers);
  JoinedRooms roomsID = JoinedRooms.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

  List names = [];

  roomsID.joinedRooms.forEach((roomID) async {
    await roomState(accessToken, roomID).then((value) async {
      await names.add(value[6].content.name);
    });

  return names;
  });
```

The following values are coming for `response.body`

```
{
  "joined_rooms": [
    "!JSHWMPAgoJdkQvRQrr:example.com",
    "!WzjRnPpUASluIsGTuo: example.com"
  ]
}
```

With the `.forEach` method, I want to request the name of the group for each group id and add it to the `names` list.

```dart
Future<List<RoomState>> roomState(String accessToken, String roomID) async {
  String url = server + "/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/$roomID/state";
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken"};
  Response response = await get(url, headers: headers);
  List<RoomState> states = (json.decode(response.body) as List).map((i) => RoomState.fromJson(i)).toList();
  return states;
}
```

The list of `names` is always empty. `async` is not waiting for the snippet of code. I tried many methods but I was not successful.

Comment: are you getting values from `roomState(accessToken, roomID)`?

Comment: Did simple `for...loop` have any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting the function that run in the forEach

```
roomsID.joinedRooms.forEach((roomID) async {
  await ...
});
```

The await doesn't work because there is nothing that say to the function inside the forEach to wait.
Try the example below on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {

  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3];

  list.forEach((value) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: value));
    print('Waited $value');
  });

  print('Finished main');

}
```

The result is:

```
Finished main
Waited 1
Waited 2
Waited 3
```

Because forEach doens't wait the function inside.

Try instead:

```
for(.. in ..) {
    await ...
}
```